# Function computing interval between dates of two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I have a plpgsql block:

```
EXTRACT(day FROM TIMESTAMP (
         Select evt_start_date
         From events
         Where evt_id = oldEvtId)
      - (Select evt_start_date
         From events
         Where evt_id = newEvtId)
     ) INTO evtStartDateDiff;
```

How can I find the *date difference in days* from the query above which takes `startDate` and `endDate` as a parameter from a table.

Comment: Please don't change the question so that it would get out of sync with the given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could look like this (**SQL function**):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_days_between(
   old_evt_id int, 
  ,new_evt_id int, 
  ,OUT days_diff int) AS
$func$
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM evt_start_date
                     - (SELECT e.evt_start_date
                        FROM   events e
                        WHERE  e.evt_id = $2)
              )::int
FROM   events
WHERE  evt_id = $1;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

I simplified it and put it into a plain SQL function. Could be a **plpgsql function** as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_days_between(
   old_evt_id int, 
  ,new_evt_id int, 
  ,OUT days_diff int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
SELECT INTO days_diff
       EXTRACT(day FROM evt_start_date
                     - (SELECT e.evt_start_date
                        FROM   events e
                        WHERE  e.evt_id = old_evt_id)
              )::int
FROM   events
WHERE  evt_id = new_evt_id;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- For this simple case nest one sub-query inside the other query.
- Uses an `OUT` parameter in both cases to simplify the syntax. Voids the need for a `RETURNS` clause here. More about [`CREATE FUNCTION` in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).
- [`extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) generically returns `double precision`, `integer` seems more appropriate for the number of days, so cast to integer (`::int`) and use integer for the  `OUT` parameter.